# Filtrar palabras en python

Tags: python

Me gustaría realizar un filtro en un programa que he realizado que caza mensajes concretos de una base de datos.

He estado viendo otros post y googleando un poco, y si duplico alguna pregunta existente disculpen, pero no encuentro exactamente lo que estoy buscando.

Lo que quiero realizar es un filtro que me bloquee los textos que vienen desde la base de datos, pero el filtro que tengo echo ahora mismo no me filtra exactamente como yo quiero, ya que no filtra literalmente por lo que tengo escrito.

No sé muy bien qué criterio sigue para filtrar pero, buscando encontre esto:

```
#Keywords to ignore messages
exclude : "^(?!.*(paga|pago|expul)).*$"
```

Lo que hace por ejemplo con un texto que vi, es, si tiene en el texto "ganar" automáticamente no me lo recoge, cuando debería,

Con lo cual mi pregunta es: ¿qué método puedo utilizar en python para filtrar «literalmente» las palabras clave que yo quiera?

EDITO: 
Codigo del programa:

```
blacklist = ["paga", "pago", "expul"]

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=lambda msg: not 
is_blacklisted(msg.message, blacklist)))
async def my_event_handler(event): 
  from_channel_id = event.original_update.message.to_id.channel_id
  entity = redirections.get(from_channel_id)
  if entity:
    await event.client.send_message(entity, event.original_update.message)

def is_blacklisted(frase, palabras):
  for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra in frase:
      return True
  return False
```

Edito2:

A pesar de que el filtro funciona sin ningún error, si el mensaje contiene un salto de línea, lo filtra, aunque no contenga ninguna palabra clave como tal.

Le pasa lo mismo a la hora de utilizar una expresión regular.

Comment: Sin más contexto, ese trozo de código que has pegado no parece python. Tampoco entiendo qué significa "filtrar". Digamos que tienes una lista de palabras clave. ¿Lo que quieres es una función que, dada una lista de frases y la de palabras clave te retorne una lista con las frases que _no_ contienen ninguna de las palabras clave?

Comment: si no lo he entendido mal, ¿estas buscando una expresión regular [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html) para aplicarla a una base de datos en `python`?

Comment: @abulafia va relacionado con los mensajes del otro post que puse de manejo de listas de python, https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/412176?noredirect=1.
Lo que quiero es filtrar algunos de los mensajes que recibo, ya que contienen informacion poco relevante.
el fragmento de codigo, es otro diccionario del fichero .yml que utiliza mi programa python.

Comment: @meegle84 estoy buscando que algunos mensajes que siempre traen el mismo cuerpo, se filtren ya que la información que contiene no es relevante, realmente la consulta no es sobre una base de datos, con lo cual lo que necesito es que filtre tal cual, las palabras o conjunto de palabras que yo le indico en el diccionario

Comment: Si pudiera usar una expresión regular seria perfecto, ya que por motivos de rendimiento me es mucho mas útil que tener un método comprobando cada mensaje, pero si no es posible, no quedara mas remedio. @meegle84

Comment: puedes hacerlo con `re.search(patron, stringdondebuscarpatron)`, donde `patron` seria la expresión regular como la que has puesto `"^(?!.*(paga|pago|expul)).*$"`

Comment: @meegle84, pero esa expresión esta mal hecha, ya que por ejemplo si pongo   "algo" ya no lo envía porque filtra el go, osea no está funcionando bien, esta mal echa, y la rehice, pero de la manera que lo rehice que es esta: "^.*(?:paga|pago|expul).*$" no v. 
Si te fijas, ^.*(?:   =  ^(?!.* no son iguales, pero la primera no va y la segunda filtra mal

Comment: prueba con algo como `(.*)pago|paga|expul(.*)`

Comment: Probado, asi: "^(.*)pago|paga|expul(.*)$" y asi "(.*)pago|paga|expul(.*)" y no envia nada. :((  Yo creo que ya no es culpa de la expresión en si, si no del pattern que yo le pongo en el método y limitación del propio framwork porque si no no me lo explico, gracias por tu ayuda @meegle84

Comment: Haciendo pruebas, me he dado cuenta de que mi expresión regular falla por culpa de los saltos de linea, existe alguna forma de realizar una expresión que tenga en cuento los saltos de línea? @meegle84

Comment: según lo dicho en la respuesta aceptada de [SOes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901523/whats-a-faster-operation-re-match-search-or-str-find) es mas conveniente para la eficiencia la respuesta de @abulafia

Comment: lo se, y es la que trataré de hacer, pero me desquiciaba no saber porque no funcionaba la expresión regular @meegle84

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo siguiente sería una función genérica que te retorna `True` si la `frase` que le pasas contiene como subcadena alguna de las que le pasas en el parámetro `blacklist`:

```
def is_blacklisted(frase, palabras):
  for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra in frase:
      return True
  return False
```

Esto puedes usarlo para filtrar una lista, por ejemplo la lista siguiente:

```
frases =[
    "En un lugar de la Mancha ",
    "de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme ",
    "no ha mucho tiempo que vivía ",
    "un hidalgo ",
    "de los de lanza en astillero, ",
    "adarga antigua, ",
    "rocín flaco, ",
    "y galgo corredor."
]

blacklist = ["de", "nombre"]

filtradas = [frase for frase in frases if not is_blacklisted(frase, blacklist)]
```

con el resultado:

```
['no ha mucho tiempo que vivía ',
 'un hidalgo ',
 'adarga antigua, ',
 'rocín flaco, ',
 'y galgo corredor.']
```

Observa que lo que busca es la sub-cadena. Si pones `["a"]` en `blacklist` no pasaría ninguna. Por otro lado esta versión es sensible al caso (mayus/minus), puede modificarse fácilmente para que no lo sea:

```
def is_blacklisted(frase, palabras):
  for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra.lower() in frase.lower():
      return True
  return False
```

### Actualización

La función `events.NewMessage()` que usa tu framework admite un parámetro llamado `pattern`, el cual, además de una expresión regular, puede ser una función que recibirá como parámetro el mensaje y devolverá como resultado `True` si ese mensaje debe ser manejado.

La función que proporcioné antes (`is_blacklisted()`) no sirve directamente para este propósito, pues por un lado recibe dos parámetros en vez de uno, y por otro lado retorna lo contrario de lo que se espera (`True` indica que el mensaje no debe ser manejado). Pero es trivial hacer una expresión `lambda` que haga uso de ella y se ajuste a lo que se necesita.

Lo siguiente debería funcionar (aunque no he podido testearlo por carecer de la infrasctructura necesaria):

```
blacklist = ["paga", "pago", "expul"]
@client.on(events.NewMessage(
              pattern=lambda msg: not is_blackisted(msg, blacklist)))
async def my_event_handler(event):
  from_channel_id = event.original_update.message.to_id.channel_id
  entity = redirections.get(from_channel_id)
  if entity:
    await event.client.send_message(entity, event.original_update.message)
```

Comment: OH! Muchísimas gracias, contaba con que tuviera algún error en la sintaxis, pero la verdad que esta muchísimo mejor la manera que me propones. Lo probare ahora por la noche y te digo que tal, aunque vamos, mas claro el agua.. :))

Comment: he intentado adaptarlo, la verdad me ha sido muy util, pero a la hora de aplicarlo a mi programa, yo realmente donde necesito aplicar el filtro es antes de enviar el mensaje, yo lo envio con event.client.send_message(entity, event.original_update.message) donde entity es el diccionario de canales y lo otro los mensajes correspondientes mañana le edito la pregunta, muchas gracias por tu ayuda :D

Comment: Disculpame, que no lo viera, lo voy a probar ahora mismo. Muchas gracias @abulafia

Comment: Me tira un error en el async def que dice "for expected" imagino que sera, porque en el my_Event_handler tengo que hacer un bucle para ir mandando los mensajes despues de comprobarlos no?

Comment: No conozco el framework que usas, pero según entendí no tendría por qué haber ningún bucle en tu código. Meramente estás registrando una función que se ejecutará cuando llegue un mensaje,  sólo si el mensaje pasa el filtro. El bucle si acaso lo gestionaría el framework. ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir el código que te tira ese error, y el _traceback_ concreto que muestra en qué línea rompe?

Comment: Hay lo tienes, no se si es exactamente lo que necesitas, pero es lo que puedo sacar de pycharm @abulafia

Comment: @Peisou Perdón, olvidé cerrar un paréntesis más justo antes del `async def`. Creo que era debido a eso que te daba el error de sintaxis (en el cual, por cierto, no dice nada de "for expected")

Comment: fallo mío, por no fijarme... confiaba que estaba correcto y tire para adelante, y si que me lo dice lo del for expected, pero en el propio editor, subrayado en rojo, me imagino que sera la sugerencia lógica que cree que podría solucionarlo..

Comment: he actualizado la pregunta, con el error que me da ahora, que es basicamente el mismo que al tratar de utilizar tu codigo la primera vez

Comment: Disculpa de nuevo. Al no tener yo ese framework no puedo probar mis respuestas antes de publicarlas. En este caso di por supuesto que el parámetro que recibía la lambda era de tipo Message, pero se ve que directamente le pasa un string. He actualizado la respuesta. Perdona por usarte de conejillo de Indias :-)

Comment: Jajajaja no pasa nada, se agradece un monton ^^ si tengo que averiguar yo todo esto echo una vida, SIII FUNCIONA!! muchisimas gracias de verdad, eres mi idolo (L) te daba ++++rep

Comment: Efectivamente, no respeta los saltos de línea, cuando metes un texto cualquiera con un salto de línea por en medio, la segunda linea la coje el filtro como no válida @abulafia. edito la pregunta.

Comment: Eso de las varias líneas no lo entiendo, quiero decir que no entiendo cómo puede estar pasando. A no ser que ... ¿será que quizás cuando hay varias líneas lo que recibe la lambda no es una cadena sino una lista de cadenas (una por línea)? ¿Podrías un `print(frase)` dentro de la función `is_blacklisted()` para comprobarlo?

Comment: Solucionado, he tenido que añadir -> text = event.original_update.message.text.rstrip()
    a = re.findall(exclude, text)

y asi ya tendria en cuenta los saltos de linea tambien. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Disculpa que te vuelva a molestar @abulafia, pero estaba trabajando de nuevo en este proyecto, y me gustaría hacer un filtro para omitir las fotos que me vienen de los dialogs, he visto que telethon tiene un método que es "InputMessagesFilterPhotos"  y he visto el siguiente ejemplo: from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterPhotos
client.get_messages(chat, 10, filter=InputMessagesFilterPhotos)"
ojála pudieras ayudarme ya llevo unos días rompiendome la cabeza y no consigo sacar imagenes. He puesto otro post por si quieres verlo. Muchas gracias de antemano.